# ¿Cómo ejecutar una acción después de acabar una animación en kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Es una animación (derechaaizquierda.xml) de 2500 ms que están indicados en el xml de la animación. El xml lleva esto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="-200%p"
        android:duration="2500"
        />
</set>
```

El código del MainActivity.kt es:

```
var delado = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.derechaaizquierda)
dibujomuñeco.startAnimation(delado)
```

Y lo que quería era que se realizara una acción después de terminar la animación.

He probado a poner un montón de código para retrasar la acción 2500 ms pero tampoco no lo he conseguido hacer, así que algo para que detecte que la animación se detuvo también me valdría.

Comment: Agrégale un Listener a la animación e implementa el callback `onAnimationEnd`.

Comment: Como comenta Glenn usa  AnimationListener, para saber cuando termina la animación e iniciar una nueva.

Answer (score 0):

Para detectar cuando inicia o termina una animación, define un [**AnimationListener**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener), al terminar la primera animación define la segunda animación, ejemplo:

```
 var delado = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.derechaaizquierda)
 var otraAnimacion = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.otra_animacion)

 dibujomuñeco.startAnimation(delado)

 delado.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
                override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
                    //Inicia animación
                }

                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
                    //Termina animación, aquí puedes definir otra animación.
                     dibujomuñeco.startAnimation(otraAnimacion)
                }

                override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAnimationRepeat()")
                }
            })
```

[image: Jorgesys Irina Ioana Bosca]